# Should you explicitly declare an instance name in the code?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to ActionScript.

When I create a MovieClip and attach an instance name to it, I have access to it via the class of the stage.

However, I saw some tutorials that explicitly declare a variable with the instance name.

Is there any particular reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of confusion in your post, so let me clarify things for you, maybe.

You can instantiate (create an instance of) class with **new** operator. Yes, with the **new** operator you can omit () if there are no mandatory arguments, it's not an error.

```
new MovieClip;
```

You can assign the result of that operation to a variable, declared as the variable of exact class.

```
var M:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
```

Or any superclass of the class you instantiate.

```
var D:DisplayObject = new MovieClip;
var E:EventDispatcher = new MovieClip;
```

Or an untyped variable.

```
var U:* = new MovieClip;
```

The variable type is what compiler looks at when you work with the referenced object (with no regard to actual object's class):

```
// Fine, DisplayObject.name is a valid property.
D.name = "Movie1";

// Error, EventDispatcher does not have a name property.
E.name = "Movie2";
```

Then. Setting an instance name is meaningful if you are going to access that instance as a child of some container with **getChildByName(...)** method. Or, maybe, if you are going to have a lot of different children in one container and you want to store their meta-essence in their names, like "Enemy2" or "Bullet15".

But it is not mandatory. If you can/want organize your app so that all references are stored as variables or in **Array**s, there's no need to name instances.

Comment: Thanks! So let's say I add a `Player` MovieClip to the stage in Animate, and I want to give it an instance name `player`, so I do it using the Properties panel (or is there another way, without dynamically adding the MovieClip?). As I understand it, Animate automatically declares a variable in the classe linked to the stage, with the name `player`. Now, In the tutorial I saw, the turor also declared excplicitly a variable `player` in the code: `var player:MovieClip`.

Why did he did that? Thanks again!

Comment: @Sipo In **File -> Publish Settings -> AS3 Settings** you can uncheck **Automatically Declare Stage Instances** and there you will have a **MovieClip** with a name "player" that IS NOT declared as a variable and accessible via **getChildByName(...)** only. I think, the author of the tutorial just wanted to express the intent of having that instance declared as a variable, also Flash autocomplete will work with declared variable better, I think.

Comment: Thanks... So should I declare them in code even after setting an instance name in Animate?

Comment: @Sipo As I said - it's not mandatory. That's up to you to decide. Autocomplete is not a bad thing, actually, it will suggest you what methods and properties the declared variable has. Also, if you proceed with AS3 and move on to classes instead of frame scripts, you will have to declare it anyway.

Comment: Thanks... I think I was not clear. I talked about class variables from the first place. What I ment is that the stage has a linked class, and if I should decleare there variables to reflect the instance names given in the properties panel, even though animate do it automatically.

Comment: @Sipo Give it a try, un-declare it. But I think Flash just won't compile a class where you try to access something that is not declared. Personally, I see no point to **not** declaring things which are there anyway.